# Problems with Requests. Site is't responsing

Tags: python, request, python-requests

I'm trying to request to `msudrf.ru` - [click](http://msudrf.ru/) 
It is supreme's court of Russia oficial website

But when i run this code:

```
import requests as req
req.get("http://msudrf.ru")
```

The program freezes on the request and does not want to run further. 
Requests to other sites like google working normal. I've tryed to add headers and do requests to `79.133.87.8:80 - ip of that site` it doesn't working too.

Comment: the site is clearly slow, have you tried timeout=60 for example?

Comment: I run my program 2 hours ago and it has not yet completed